# session overlape and interchange each other in php

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm Making a game on web browser 
i check user authentication by **Session**
all things works well on localhost 
when i upload files to server and player started to play 
the problem started to appear

### the problem simply is

i read player ID from session 
and when more than user open the server on the same time 
the IDs interchange between players
i have tried to make work around solution 
but all failed

**reading player ID**

```php
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_player"])){
        $playerId = $_SESSION["id_player"];
    }
    if($_SESSION["auth"] != returnIAuthToken()){


    exit();
   }

    session_write_close();
```

**function prevent problem**

```php
function returnIAuthToken(){
    return md5((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ?
            $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : 
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ?
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] :
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'no ua'));
}
```

**set player id**

```php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }

        $_SESSION["id_player"]     = $id_user;
        $_SESSION["auth"]   = returnIAuthToken();

        session_write_close();
```

i have do some search but found nothing

i tell the server admin about the problem 
but he told its from code 
i know it's not to seem good question 
but i don't know even where is the problem

Comment: Sessions for different clients don’t just “mix”, there must be something wrong with either how the session id is passed along, or how the session data gets stored server-side.

Comment: the problem is in reading the value client can use different value in refresh i have searched for solution for 2 days and found nothing relative

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say right now.